# How to delay a method in C# for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a method.

```
public bool bBIntersectsBT(Rect barTopTipRect, Rect barBottomTipRect, Rect blueBallRect)
    {
        barTopTipRect.Intersect(blueBallRect);
        barBottomTipRect.Intersect(blueBallRect);

        if (barTopTipRect.IsEmpty && barBottomTipRect.IsEmpty)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I want to delay this method for 2 seconds before this method is executed again. I have read up about Thread.Sleep, However, that is not what I want. I do not want the program to pause and resume it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `DispatcherTimer`:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

//TimeSpan is in format: Days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2);
timer.Tick += timerTick;
timer.Start();

private void timerTick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code you want to execute every 2 seconds

    //If you want to stop after the two seconds just add timer.Stop() here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user [Dispatch Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to achieve your goal. Set it to 2 seconds when you want. And after  you are done with it. you can stop it.